# iconview, picture shows only one

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

Good day! I want to show all the pictures in the folder, but this code
 shows only 1 image. Where is the error?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import threading
import gtk
import os  

gtk.gdk.threads_init()
class app(gtk.Window):
def __init__(self):
    gtk.Window.__init__(self)
    self.set_title("spoView")
    self.set_default_size(700, 500)
    self.connect("destroy", gtk.main_quit)

    scroll = gtk.ScrolledWindow()
    scroll.set_border_width(2)
    scroll.set_shadow_type(gtk.SHADOW_ETCHED_IN)
    scroll.set_policy(gtk.POLICY_AUTOMATIC, gtk.POLICY_AUTOMATIC)

    thumb_view = gtk.IconView()
    model = gtk.ListStore(str, gtk.gdk.Pixbuf)
    thumb_view.set_model(model)
    thumb_view.set_text_column(0)
    thumb_view.set_pixbuf_column(1)
    thumb_view.set_columns(4)

    vbox = gtk.VBox()
    status = gtk.Statusbar()

    scroll.add(thumb_view)
    vbox.pack_start(scroll, True, True)
    vbox.pack_start(status, False, False)
    self.add(vbox)
    self.show_all()

    files = os.listdir("/home/pdk/Pictures/foto2/")
    thread = threading.RLock()
    with thread:
        for image in files:
            pixbuf = gtk.gdk.pixbuf_new_from_file_at_size("/home/pdk/Pictures/foto2/%s" %image, 128, 128) 
            model.append([image, pixbuf])

    status.push(0, "%s files loaded." % len(files))     


a = app()
gtk.main()
```

Comment: what is the value of len(files) ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "2+mb". From what I read `files` should be a list of strings, and `len(files)` should return an integer value which is the number of strings in that list.

Comment: 'model.append([image, pixbuf])' , 'pixbuf = gtk...' will be under of syntax

Comment: so: `model.append([image, pixbuf])` is at same indentation level as `pixbuf = gtk.gdk.pixbuf_new_from_file_at_size("/home/pdk/Pictures/foto2/%s" %image, 128, 128)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I notice that there isn't a check for whether or not the files you're adding is a valid image before you create a pixbuf from them. If it's running into a file that isn't an image, then an error would be raised in the thread that's appending data to the model.

Before you try to create the pixbuf, you could do something like:

```
with thread:
for image in files:
    if image.endswith(".jpg"):
        pixbuf = gtk.gdk.pixbuf_new_from_file_at_size("/home/pdk/Pictures/foto2/%s" %image, 128, 128) 
        model.append([image, pixbuf])
```